# tf cast leads to TypeError: Object of type 'int32' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use tf.math.round() but the output still has decimal points (310.0, 210.0 etc)
If I use tf.cast(tf.math.round(), dtype="int32"), then I see the error mentioned in the title when calling finish on tornado handler

How can I cast to int using tensorflow operations and still be json serielizable

Answer (score 0):

You should use tf.int32 instead.